TimescaleDB not accepting intervales less than one day
I have a timescaleDB  but I cannot seem to be able to use the time_bucket method with less than one day intervals.
The code attempting to access it is running inside of a fast API and is as follows :
    async def get_candlestick_data(self, db: AsyncSession, market_name: str, resource_name: str, interval: str):
        sql = f"""
        SELECT 
            time_bucket('{interval}', timestamp) as period,
            FIRST(price, timestamp) as open,
            MAX(price) as high,
            MIN(price) as low,
            LAST(price, timestamp) as close,
            SUM(quantity) as volume
        FROM 
            resource_market_value
        WHERE
            market_name = :market_name AND resource_name = :resource_name
        GROUP BY 
            period
        ORDER BY 
            period;
        """
        result = await db.execute(text(sql), {'market_name': market_name, 'resource_name': resource_name})
        return result.fetchall()

Here is the model I am using :
from sqlalchemy import DateTime
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, BigInteger
from common_modules.database.base import Base


class ResourceMarketValue(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'resource_market_value'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    market_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    resource_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    timestamp = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    price = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    quantity = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

And here is the only configuration / edit I am doing to the table :
SELECT create_hypertable('resource_market_value', 'timestamp');

The issue is that the TimescaleDB is not accepting intervals of less than one day. Here are the logs I am getting :
2024-09-12 14:59:54.455 UTC [50740] ERROR:  interval must not have sub-day precision
2024-09-12 14:59:54.455 UTC [50740] STATEMENT:
                SELECT
                    time_bucket('15 minutes', timestamp) as period,
                    FIRST(price, timestamp) as open,
                    MAX(price) as high,
                    MIN(price) as low,
                    LAST(price, timestamp) as close,
                    SUM(quantity) as volume
                FROM
                    resource_market_value
                WHERE
                    market_name = $1 AND resource_name = $2
                GROUP BY
                    period
                ORDER BY
                    period;

2024-09-12 14:59:54.456 UTC [50741] ERROR:  could not map dynamic shared memory segment
2024-09-12 14:59:54.456 UTC [50742] ERROR:  could not map dynamic shared memory segment
2024-09-12 14:59:54.458 UTC [1] LOG:  background worker "parallel worker" (PID 50741) exited with exit code 1
2024-09-12 14:59:54.459 UTC [1] LOG:  background worker "parallel worker" (PID 50742) exited with exit code 1

What makes me very confused is that I am not seeing any for of configuration being mentioned in the documentation of the time_bucket as seen here : https://docs.timescale.com/use-timescale/latest/time-buckets/use-time-buckets/ 
If anything, it seems like I should be able to do so.
The intent with my code on the long run is to be able to have market values being displayed in a candlestick chart and I'll need to be able to have up to 15 minutes per candle as minimum and 1 day as maximum.
Currently the only data in the database is test data that I inserted. There is one entry per minute, no more.
Ideally, if possible, I would like to automate the configuration and not navigate to a web page if changing configuration is needed.
Edit : the version of timescaleDB I am using is the 2.16.1 as seen here :
psql (14.12)
Type "help" for help.

timescaledb=# SELECT default_version, installed_version FROM pg_available_extensions WHERE name = 'timescaledb';
 default_version | installed_version
-----------------+-------------------
 2.16.1          | 2.16.1
(1 row)

timescaledb=# SELECT version();
                                                    version
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 14.12 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 13.2.1_git20240309) 13.2.1 20240309, 64-bit
(1 row)

I will also add that it is as unconfigured as it can get. It has the password and username through environ values and that is it.

I never saw such error before, are you sure it's related to the timescale?
Because you can build aggregation in any time frame. Check https://github.com/jonatas/sql-snippets/blob/master/caggs_cascade.sql#L14

Every source I have read completely agrees with you. I have even just attempted to connect to the database itself and run the commands with pure SQL ( no SqlAlchemy ) just in case but I get the exact same error. I am wondering if I am not using the query correctly by giving the wrong arguments or if there is a configuration that I am not aware of that is not in a state that it should be in.

The database now works fine.
What seems to have happened is that the table what not a hypertable. I had code in order to make sure that it was one but there is a catch : by default, a table cannot be converted to a hypertable if the table possesses some data.
It's quite frustrating that I did not see anything mentioned in the documentation of the time_bucket method about this and the error was not explicit about the topic.

Have you updated to latest versions? because the error is not present in latest versions.
Also, the param migrate_data is described in the optional arguments here: https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hypertable/create_hypertable/#optional-arguments

Also, thanks for the feedback around your frustration with our docs. We made improvements in the time_bucket docs. We added a link to hypertables to make it clear.

I was using the latest version as described in the edit of the question ( or at least it was the latest version when the post was made ). I had not seen the migrate data part of the documentation which would have saved me some time ( damn it ).

Much appreciated for the documentation. If there are other similar methods that are dependant on hypertables specifically I would recommend also linking the doc there too.

It seems you're using version 1.7 or less of Timescaledb.
Please, update to latest versions to confirm that the error will disappear.

I just edited my question with the command lines I used to check the version but it does seem like I am using the latest versions there is. There is also no configuration at all except for username and password through environ values.
